# Centered Element

Tags: html, css

I Am Started Learning HTML And CSS And I Wanna Know :
How i Could Make This links Home And About And Contact Centered In Header

Html :

```
 <body>
    <header>
        
        <h1><a href="#">HBT</a> </h1>
        <nav>

            
                <a href="./home.html">Home</a>
                <a href="./about.html">About</a>
                <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
            
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Style :

```
*{
    margin:0;
    
}

header{
    background-color:#000;
overflow: hidden;
height:90px;
}

header h1{
    float :left;
}
header nav a{
    float :right;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean padding: 150px?

Comment: this sounds like an X/Y problem. I suppose you want to make  `a` full height and center the text inside, right?

Comment: Hey, @Majd Soubh. Do you mean that you want to place link to the bottom of header?

Answer (score 1):

Since `<a>` is an inline element, you will need to convert that into block element. Further, padding isn't your option here because. You will need 100% height.

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```